# How to use VB to capture screen and then get the pixel information?

Tags: vb.net, screenshot

I find an example in MS website. It tells me how to do screen capture in VB and display the picture. However, it is not exactly what I want. I want to capture the screen and then know the RGB value of point (x,y). How I can do that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e7y164x) class (I assume you do), use the [GetPixel()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel.aspx) method to get the color of a specific coordinate.

---

**Example:**

```
' Get the color of 12, 12
Dim pixelColor As Color = yourBitmap.GetPixel(12, 12)
```

---

The [Color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx) structure returned by this method has the properties you're looking for.

---

**Example:**

```
Dim g = pixelColor.G
Dim b = pixelColor.B
Dim r = pixelColor.R
Dim a = pixelColor.A
Dim text = String.Format("Alpha:{0}, red:{1}, green: {2}, blue {3}", New Object() {a, r, g, b})
```

Comment: Haha. Actually, I am very new to VB. I will use the Bitmap class to do my task from now. Thanks

Comment: @Marco What did you use to capture the the screen if not `Bitmap`? Just curious

Answer (score 0):

You can use opencv library functions for knowing the RGB value of point.